# Java easiest way to assign default variable value with OR?

Tags: java

I read data from a csv file and would like to assign the column values to variables. There might be the case that the file does not contain the desired field. I would then like to assign a default value. I would like something similar to this:

```
String country = nextLine[columnIndices.get("country")] || "Austria";
```

What is the most elegant way without a lot of ifs. (I am new to java from C#)

Comment: you can use a ternary operator

Comment: Which part represents lack of value? Is it when `columnIndices.get("country")` returns something like -1, or `nextLine[columnIndices.get("country")]` will contain `null`?

Answer (score 9):

Use a method:

```
private String valueOrDefault(String value, String defaultValue) {
    return value == null ? defaultValue : value; 
}

...

String country = valueOrDefault(nextLine[columnIndices.get("country")], "Austria");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
String country = (nextLine[columnIndices.get("country")] != null) ? nextLine[columnIndices.get("country")] : "default";
```

Comment: The only drawback of this method is that the condition is evaluated twice, what may/maynot be wanted

Comment: if it is necessary to also check for empty strings then StringUtils.isBlank(str) method of the apache commons library might be helpful:

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8 you can also use

```
String s = Optional.ofNullable(fooStr).orElse("bar");
// may be null ----------------^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first option(s) cannot throw a `NullPointerException`, I would recommend Apache Commons' [firstNonNull](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#firstNonNull(T...))

It allows you to pass **any amount of arguments** and it will return the first not-null value.

```
String country = ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(nextLine[columnIndices.get("country")], "Austria");
// Add more arguments if needed
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple if statement can solve it:

```
String country = nextLine[columnIndices.get("country")];
if (country == null)
    country = "Austria";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to use Java 8, you can use Optional.

```
 Long value = findOptionalLong(ssn).orElse(0L);
```

This sets value to a number or 0 if not found.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and readable one:

```
String country = nextLine[columnIndices.get("country")];
country = (country != null) ? country : "Austria";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or create a generic method

```
static <T> T nvl(T first, T ifFirstNull) {
    return (first != null ? first : ifFirstNull);
}
```

And you can use it for any Objects